# C Programming - Lotto Simulation

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, random

I am making a program to simulate the lotto. The numbers can range between 1-45, but the numbers drawn must be unique. The program generates 6 random numbers in this range and adds them to an array. The user enters their numbers and the program checks if the 2 arrays are the same i.e whether they have won the lotto or not.

I don't know why, but my program doesn't generate the random numbers, nor does it check if they're equal.

```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> 
> int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
>     // insert code here...
>     int lotto[6];
>     int i;
> 
>     int user[6];
>     for(i=0; i<6; i++){
>         printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 45: \n");
>         scanf("%d", &user[i]);
>     }
>     printf("User's numbers: \n");
>     for(i=0; i<6; i++){
>         printf("%d \n", user[i]);
>     }
>     printf("Generate 6 Random Lotto Numbers \n");
>     
>     
>     for(i=0; i<6;i++){
>          lotto[i] = rand() % 45 + 1;
>      }
>     for(i=0; i<6; i++){
>         printf("%d \n",lotto[i]);
>      }
> 
>     
>     
>     
>      for(i=0; i<6; i++){
>          if(lotto[i] != user[i]){
>              printf("Hard luck. Try again next time.");
>              break;
>          }
>          else{
>              printf("You've won the lotto!");
>          }
>      
>     }
>      return 0; }
```

Some typos in the code were pointed out to me. I also added a piece of code, but I am going to comment it because I am unsure if it's the right approach needed for what I want to do.

Any help would be extremely helpful and I'd be even more grateful. :)

Comment: Why do you have a `scanf`` in your generator loop???

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you familiar with a debugger to follow your program step by step and see what happens?

Comment: You appear to be overwriting your random numbers with input scanned from `STDIN`.

Comment: Yea I am aware. I forgot to take out the scanf part.

Comment: I took that out and now it generates the random numbers fine. However I do not know how to check if the numbers can be repeated or how stop the user entering numbers above 50 and under 1.

    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
        printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 45: \n");
        if(user[i] < 1 && user[i] >45){
            printf("Please enter a valid number.");
            i--;
        }
        else{
            scanf("%d", &user[i]);
        }

Comment: As a small point, you need `lotto[i] = rand() % 45 + 1;` to generate numbers in the range `1..45`, not `lotto[i] = rand() % 46 + 1;`

Comment: Which? The required range or the code?

Comment: So how much of this question contains "accidental" errors in posting and how much contains errors you "forgot to take out", and, how are we supposed to know the difference?

Comment: @WeatherVane Those were two small errors. The other parts I am asking for help with are actual questions and parts of the question I don't know how to do.

Comment: Rather than needing to check for duplicates, I would create an ordered list of numbers, 1-45, generate 6 random numbers between _n_ and 44 (_n_ is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, in that order), and swap the array entry at _n_ with the value at your current random number... very scalable and automatically no duplicates. Then if you sort the first _n_ numbers in the array, it's easy to compare to the user's (sorted) data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for checking the lotto is to sort both arrays, then your incorrect comparison between user [i] and lotto[i] will then work

To avoid duplicates a new function is required  , which takes new value, array, max index as parameters. This needs to check if new value exists in the first (max index-1) elements. You need to check for duplicates in all 6 iterations of both creation of lotto data and after each scanf for user input data.